# Does JetBrains Rider support Azure Service Fabric application?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am new to Azure development and specificity to Azure Service Fabric. I find Visual Studio not rich as IntelliJ IDE. I installed the Rider IDE but it seems that it doesn't support a Service Fabric application.
Is there a plugin for a service fabric project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it [doesn't](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10370) support running and debugging SF projects.

Comment: Is there a plan to add support in the near future?

Comment: @ShimonShrem I suggest to ask devs directly in that Rider ticket